# How to save query.count result of parse cloud code in a variable?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am new to parse cloud code. I have written a function in which I am trying to get the count of particular procedure on the basis of adapter name (user-input). My code below is :

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("getProcedureList",function (req, res)
{
    var resultCount;
    var query = new Parse.Query("mst_logReports");
    query.limit(10);

    query.equalTo("adapterName",req.params.adapterName);
    query.find({
        success: function (result) {
            var resultArr = [];
            var resultlen = result.length;

            var tempArr = {};
            if (resultlen > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < resultlen; i++) {
                    tempArr = {

                        "procedure":result[i].get("procedure") : 

                        // (here I want the count of this procedure). 
                        // How to use query.count inside this for loop 
                        // so that I can get the counts? 

                    }
                    resultArr.push(tempArr);
                }
            }
            res.success(resultArr);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            res.success(error);
        }
    })
 });
```

Note : The code is working fine. But I am not able to get the count of that particular procedure in my code above.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Too many requests on cloud code is not suitable, it has 15 sec only. The better way is maintaining a count on your mst_logReports object.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot catch what you want exactly.

I assume that you want to get counts by each mst_logReports object.

```
success: function (result) {
    var resultArr = [];
    var resultlen = result.length;

    var tempArr = {};
    if (resultlen > 0) {
        var promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < resultlen; i++) {
            var report = result[i];
            var query = new Parse.Query('???');
            query.equalTo('xxx', report.get('qqq'));
            promises.push(query.count());
        }
        Parse.Promise.when(promises)
        //arguments.length will equalTo promises.length, or declare arg1, arg2 ... to fit resultLen
        .then(function(){
            //get all count success

            var counts = arguments;
            for(var i=0; i<counts.length; i++){
                //why this object end with : ????
                tempArr = {
                    "procedure":result[i].get("procedure") : 
                }

                resultArr.push(tempArr);
            }
            res.success(resultArr);
        }, res.error);
    } else {
        res.success(resultArr);
    }
}
```

Too many requests on cloud code is not suitable, it has 15 sec only. The better way is maintaining a count on your mst_logReports object. You can use increment in the afterSave(make sure it have been saved).

===================edited=================

The mst_logReports contain 2 field, which are adapterName(String) and procedure (String).

***mst_logReports***

```
adapter, procedure
A, x
A, x
A, y
B, x
B, y
```

your user input A

you want to get [{x:2},{y,1}]

```
var procedureCnts = {};
for(var i=0; i<counts.length; i++){
    var procedure = result[i].get("procedure");
    if(procedureCnts[procedure]){
        procedureCnts[procedure]++;
    }else{
        procedureCnts[procedure] = 0;
    }
}
for(var key in procedureCnts){
    tempArr = {
        "procedure" : key,
        "count": procedureCnts
    }
    resultArr.push(tempArr);
}

res.success(resultArr);
```

Sadly, this function cannot scale, due to query.limit cannot >1000.

If all procedure type **is fixed**. You can try below (as my first answer way)

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getProcedureList",function (req, res)
{
    var possibleProcedures = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
    var promises = [];
    var results = [];
    for(var i=0; i<possibleProcedures.length; i++){
        var query = new Parse.Query("mst_logReports");
        query.equalTo("adapterName", req.params.adapterName);
        query.equalTo("procedure", possibleProcedures[i]);
        promises.push(query.count());
    }

    //Parse.Promise.when() is closed to es6 Promise.all()
    Parse.Promise.when(promises)
    //arguments.length will equalTo promises.length, or declare arg1, arg2 ... to fit resultLen
    .then(function(){
        //promises.length == arguments.length

        for(var i=0; i< arguments.length; i++){
            results.push({
                "procedure": possibleProcedures[i],
                "count": arguments[i]
            });
        }
        res.success(results);
    }, res.error);

});
```

If the possible procedure **is not fixed**, I cannot find a correct solution to fit your problem.

================other solution==============

The next way is more flexible and avoid too many api-request. And query.count() is slow and loading too high for db.

You should maintain 2 class, Adapter and Procedure.

```
Adapter: name(string), procedureCnt(jsonObject)
Procedure: adapter(pointer of adapter), name(string)
```

saveProcedure

```
function(adapterName){
    var query = new Parse.Query("Adapter");
    query.equalTo("name", adapterName);
    query.first().then(
        function(adapter){
            if(adapter){
                var Procedure = Parse.Object.extend("Procedure");
                var procedure = new Procedure();
                procedure.set('adapter', adapter);
                procedure.save().then(response.success, response.error);
            }else{
                response.error("the adapter is not exist");
            }
        }, response.error
    );
}
```

AfterSave of Procedure:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Procedure", function(req) {
    var procedure = req.object;
    var adapter = procedure.get('adapter');
    var key = 'procedureCnt.' + procedure.get('name');
    adapter.increment(key, 1);
    adapter.save();
});
```

AfterDelete of Procedure:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterDelete("Procedure", function(req) {
    var procedure = req.object;
    var adapter = procedure.get('adapter');
    var key = 'procedureCnt.' + procedure.get('name');
    adapter.increment(key, -1);
    adapter.save();
});
```

query cnt of a Adapter

```
function(name){
    var query = new Parse.Query("Adapter");
    query.equalTo('name', name);
    query.first().then(
        function(adapter){
            if(adapter){
                response.success(adapter.get('procedureCnt'));
            }else{
                response.error('adapter not found');
            }
        }, reponse.error
    );
}
```

The only problem is that AfterSave is not always success.
Not suggest that, you can still do lot of query.count() by Parse.Promise.when().
The usage is in one of above codes.

Comment: Thanks ChunTingLin for your help. But I want to know how to use query.count method inside that loop so that I can get the counts of procedure only, not of whole table objects and that also using query.count not using taking any variable or loop for that.  Waiting for your updated answer. Thanks

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean. Can you update your code as close as what you want?

Comment: what is "counts of procedure", what is the type of mst_logReports.procedure? why you want query.count? query to what class, and the constraint is what?

Comment: I have a table named "mst_logReports". In that I have various fields, and two among them are (adapterName and procedureName).
I am taking adaptername from the user-input and on the basis of that adapterName I want to show the procedures related to that adapteronly.
And with that Procedures , I want their count also
This is the output I am getting.
{
    "result": [
        {
       "procedureName": "getUserWithPassword"
             Counts :   I want count of this procedure here. (2).
        },{ "procedureName": "getUserWithPassword"
     Counts :}} The code is same as mention above

Comment: Thanks  ChunTingLin for your time and answer. I have tried your solutions , it works if a procedure name is fixed. But in my case, its not fixed. Is there any other way of doing it , if procedure name is not fixed. ?And sorry for the delay. Thanks again

Comment: I prefer last solution which need to restruct your DB, which can handle not fixed procedure. There a little difference of real and the count you maintained. You can host a daily script to check and correct it.

Comment: BTW, there are 2 shortcoming of query.count(). One is a size limit 500K(query with constraint) and the other is loading too high. If you try to query a big collection(and no index), it have big chance to > 10sec to response.  You should avoid count api as possible as you can, because it will results in almost whole collection scan(no index case)